# If $A$ is non-singular (invertible) and $A+E$ is singular (not-invertible) show $K_p(A)\geq \dfrac{||A||_p}{||E||_p}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a non-singular (invertible) matrix and we denote its $p$-norm with $||A||_p$ which is:
$$||A||_p = \underset{x\neq 0}{\text{max}} \dfrac{||Ax||_p}{||x||_p}$$
which $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Also $K_p(A)$ is its condition number equal to $||A||_p||A^{-1}||_p$. Now assume we add matrix $E$ to $A$ such that $A+E$ is a singular (not-invertible) matrix. Show $$K_p(A)\geq \dfrac{||A||_p}{||E||_p}$$
This is what I tried: 
$$\begin{align}
K_p(A)&\geq \dfrac{||A||_p}{||E||_p}\\||A||_p||A^{-1}||_p&\geq \dfrac{||A||_p}{||E||_p} 
\end{align}$$
Here, if $||A||_p$ is zero, we are done. Else:
$$\begin{align}
||A^{-1}||_p&\geq \dfrac{1}{||E||_p}\\
||A^{-1}||_p||E||_p&\geq 1 
\end{align}$$

Here's where I'm stuck. I also know:
$$\begin{align}
1=||I||_p=||AA^{-1}||_p\leq ||A||_p||A^{-1}||_p
\end{align}$$

But I can't go further to prove what question is asking for. I don't know how to connect that $A+E$ is singular to these inequalities.

Any help or hint is immensely valuable to me!

Comment: When you say $p$-norm, do you mean induced $p$-norm?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. added the definition to the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\in N(A+E)$ nonzero, where $N(A+E)$ is the nullspace of $A+E$ (remember that $A+E$ is singular) we have
$$
0 = (A+E)x\implies Ax=-Ex\implies x=-A^{-1}Ex
$$
Thus
$$
1=\frac{\|A^{-1}Ex\|_p}{\|x\|_p}\leq\|A^{-1}E\|_p\leq\|A^{-1}\|_p\|E\|_p.
$$

Comment: It looks nice but I didn't get the part you said $x\in N(A+E)$ nonzero, so you concluded $0=(A+E)x$. What is $N(A+E)$ notation? Null space?

Comment: @MasonRashford see edit